# Detect which Scene is up in ViewController ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

Basically I have four scenes and on viewcontroller, I want to detect in which scene am I because, I have background music in viewcontroller, and I want to pause music in some Scenes. I found how to detect scenes in viewController, but it was in swift, and I know only basics of objective c.
**Edited**

```
SKView *skView =(SKView *)self.view;
TitleScene *sceneTitle = [TitleScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
BonusScene *sceneBonus = [BonusScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
GameScene *sceneGame = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
DifficultScene *sceneDifficult = [DifficultScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size]; 

   if(skView){
        if(sceneTitle){
            NSLog(@"Iam in sceneTitle");
        }
        if(sceneGame){
            NSLog(@"Iam in sceneGame");
        }
        if(sceneDifficult){
            NSLog(@"Iam in sceneDifficult");
        }
        if(sceneBonus){
        NSLog(@"Iam in sceneBonus");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"else");
        }

}
```

now, when start app, it runs through every if statement once,even when Iam only in TitleScene. **What did wrong?**

Comment: You want to know which view controller you are on right??

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq basically,yes

Comment: What is wrong in non programming terms is you make a baby, let's call this baby TitleScene.  Then you make another baby also named TitleScene.  You are asking if baby 1 is the same as baby 2.  Even though both babies share the same name, they are not the same baby.  This is why my answer said to use the actual name variable,  Then, instead of making 2 babies, you only have 1 baby, and you are asking if the baby's name is TitleScene

Comment: With your edit,  you are now making 4 babies, and just saying, does the 4 babies exist?, again, not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Give each scene a name, then in your viewcontroller class, just do

SWIFT:

```
if let skView = view as? SKView, let scene = skView.scene
{
   switch(scene.name)
   {
     case "name1":
     default:()
   }


}
else
{
   //Something is wrong, we do not have an SKView or a SKScene
}
```

Objective C:

```
SKView *view = (SKView*)self.view ;
if(view)
{
    SKScene *scene = view.scene;
    if(scene)
    {
        NSString *name = scene.name;

       //compare names here
    }
}
```

Comment: amm, can you translate it in objective c?

Comment: Sorry about that,  I wrote some objective c,  I do not remember if switch works on strings (I want to say it doesnt), so you need to do a string comparison on the name with if statements

Comment: hi, I edited my post, can you tell me whats wrong with my code, but I didn't use `NSString`

Comment: you didnt even follow my code, your way doesn't work because you create a new instance, just set the name and use the name

Comment: e.g.  in your titlescene.m file,  override `initWithSize(...)` do `[self setName:"TitleScene"];`